# JS screen size click

Tags: javascript, click

I made this js script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    if($(window).width()<768) $("#button-opl").on('click',function(){
        $("#views-exposed-form-attraktioner-block").slideToggle();  
    }); 
});
```

But now I want to add, if the screen is bigger then 768, then the click should be disabled. How do I do that?

thannks

Comment: Your code already does that. If the window width is less than 768, your click event won't be attached to your button.

Comment: I want it to update when the window is resized

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to evaluate the screen size when the document has loaded you could do the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  const width = $(window).width();

  if (width < 768) {
    // Do something
    $("#button-opl").on('click', function() {
      $("#views-exposed-form-attraktioner-block").slideToggle();
    });
  } else if (width >= 768) {
    // Do something else
    $("#button-opl").prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

However, if you wanted to enable/disable the button dynamically based on when the screen size changes (user manually resizes the window) you would need to use an event listener and evaluate each time the window is resized like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#button-opl").on('click', function() {
    $("#views-exposed-form-attraktioner-block").slideToggle();
  });

  const reviewScreenWidth = function() {
    const width = $(window).width();
    if (width < 768) {
      // Do something
      $("#button-opl").prop('disabled', false);

    } else if (width >= 768) {

      // Do something else
      $("#button-opl").prop('disabled', true);
    }
  }

  // Call once when the page has loaded
  reviewScreenWidth();

  // Call every time the screen size changes
  window.addEventListener("resize", reviewScreenWidth);
});
```

Comment: I would like to enable/disable the button dynamically based on when the screen size changes. How to do that? Can you give an example?

Comment: Yes, but now when I click, it opens and closes in a loop.

Comment: Apologies, I noticed the code added the on click listener every time the event fired. I have moved the on click event listener out of the resize listener. See the updated code block.

Comment: hmm, your code worked the first time, but now with the new update, the button is active, no matter screen size.

The button should only be active for smartphones/tablets, and disabled when on pc.

Comment: I've amended once again to ensure the screen size is evaluated once when the page loads and then every time the screen size changes.

Comment: Thats strange. When I test your script on jsfiddle, it works, but when I add it to my site, the button is active no matter screen size. Dont get it.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161204/discussion-between-luke-stoward-and-bel).

Answer (score 1):

You basically just need to bind an event to window if the window resizes. luckily, jQuery already does this for you. So, just go straightforward for it! This is a testeable snippet that shows you how to bind and log such event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script>      
    $( window ).resize(function() {
          $( "#log" ).append( "window was resize!!!");
        });
  </script>
<body>
    <h5 id="log"></h5>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the window size can change, you should always bind the event but only act on it if the condition is met.

```
$(function() {
  $("#button-opl").on("click",function() {
    if( innerWidth < 768) {
      // ^ WAY faster than building a jQ object for a property that's already standard ;)
      $("#views-exposed-form-attraktioner-block").slideToggle();
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I would like to enable/disable the button dynamically based on when the screen size changes. How to do that? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Bel You will need a `resize` event on the window, and dis-/enable the button according to the value of `innerWidth`.